# Make variable class member outside of constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, member

Basically, I need to set a variable outside of the constructor and make it accessible to the entire class.

It would need to work something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename MT>
class CallbackFunction
{
    void (*func)(MT);
    MT *data;

  public:
    void SetCallbackData (void (*f)(MT), MT *d)
    {
        func = f;
        data = d;
    }
    void Call()
    {
        func(data);
    }
};

class Callback
{
  public:
    template <typename T>
    void SetCallback(CallbackFunction <T> *func)
    {
        // Need to make this a class member;
        CallbackFunction <T> *CallbackClass = func;
    }
    void Call()
    {
        CallbackClass->Call();
    }
};

template <typename CT>
Callback *NewCallback(void (*func)(CT), CT *data)
{
    Callback *cb;
    CallbackFunction <CT> *cf;
    cf->SetCallbackData(func, data);
    cb->SetCallback <CT> (cf);
    return cb;
};

void Call(Callback *CallbackFunc)
{
    CallbackFunc->Call();
}

void foo(std::string str)
{
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::string *str;
    str->append("Hello, World!");
    Call( NewCallback(foo, str) );
    return 0;
}
```

More details:

I know it's buggy, and it doesn't compile, I'll sort out those bugs when I find a solution to my problem. Which is:

I need to find a way to declare a template variable inside a member function of the class "Callback". I need to do this because the class "Callback" cannot be a template, it needs to remain a simple class. So because the class "Callback" is not a template, I need to make one of it's member functions a template instead. So that member function can declare a variable of the type defined (with the template) when the function is called, and this variable needs to be accessible to the entire class.

So in a nice list:

- class "Callback" cannot be a template,
- variable CallbackClass must be accessible to the entire class,
  but remain inside of the class.

Comment: OK, can you iterate over why you can't achieve what you want, and what exactly it is you want. Do you want CallbackClass to be a class member? Why it cannot be a class member? Because Callback class would have to be templated as well, or due to other problems?

Comment: @thephpdev can you be more precise on what problem you're trying to solve exactly? Your current explanation is unclear and the presented code isn't clarifying anything. Note you're example code is also buggy since it's accessing uninitialized pointers.

Comment: I know it's buggy, I'll sort out those bugs when I find a solution to my problem. Which is:

I need to find a way to declare a template variable inside a member function of the class "Callback". I need to do this because the class "Callback" cannot be a template, it needs to remain a simple class. So because the class "Callback" is not a template, I need to make one of it's member functions a template instead. So that member function can declare a variable of the type defined (with the template) when the function is called, and this variable needs to be accessible to the entire class.

Comment: I have edited my question and added more information.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <memory>

    template <typename MT> 
    class CallbackFunction
    {
        typedef void (*func_ptr)(MT);
        func_ptr f_ptr;
        typedef std::shared_ptr<MT> data_ptr;
        data_ptr data_p;
        public:
            void SetCallbackData (func_ptr f_ptr_, MT *d)
            {
                f_ptr = f_ptr_;
                data_p.reset(d);
            }
            void Call()
            {
                if ( f_ptr ) f_ptr(data);
            }
    };
    template<class T>
    class Callback
    {
        public:
            template <typename T>
            void SetCallback(CallbackFunction <T> *func)
            {
                f_ptr.reset(func);
            }
            void Call()
            {
                if ( f_ptr ) f_ptr->Call();
            }
            typedef std::shared_ptr<CallbackFunction<T>> func_ptr;
            static  func_ptr f_ptr;
    };
```

Comment: There's one problem with that, the Callback class, cannot be a template, it has to remain a simple class. This is because the function that takes this class as a parameter doesn't know which type to expect whether it be Callback <int> or Callback <std::string> in your case.

Comment: Don't want to be harsh, but if you said this in the beginning it would save user2496553 some work. It is not clear from your question what the contraints are, and what is the core of the problem you describe.

Comment: Yes, I apologise, I don't usually ask for help, I usually try to do it all myself. So I think I'm just not used to asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this using polymorphism. Your programming skills seem good so I will just sketch the direction to solution, feel free to ask for more help if needed.

```
// your callbackobjects inherit from this class, the sole purpose of this 
// class is to provide the Call interface. The derived classes implement
// their custom version of Call(). 

class CallBackObject{
public:
   virtual void Call(){};
};

class Callback
{
  CallBackObject *callBackObject;

  public:

    void SetCallback(CallBackObject *o)
    {
        callBackObject = o;
    }

    void Call()
    {
        callBackObject -> Call();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an abstract interface Callback class and have your `CallbackFunction<T>` inherit from this. Have your `Callback` class hold a pointer to this abstract interface. Finally, have your `Callback::SetCallback` assign `func` to this pointer.

Here's some code to illustrate the idea:

```
class ICallback
{
  public:
    virtual ~ICallback() {}
    virtual void Call() = 0;
};

template <typename MT>
class CallbackFunction : public ICallback
{
    typedef void (*callback)(MT);
    callback myfunc;
    MT *data;

  public:
    CallbackFunction (callback f, MT *d) :
        myfunc (f),
        data (d)
        {}
    void Call()
    {
        if(myfunc && data)
        {
          myfunc(*data);
        }
        else throw std::logic_error("Callback function or data is null!");
    }
};
```

Then have `Callback` hold a `ICallback*`:

```
class Callback
{
    ICallback *mycallback;

  public:
    template <typename T>
    void SetCallback(CallbackFunction <T> *func)
    {
        // Need to make this a class member;
        // CallbackFunction <T> *CallbackClass = func;
        mycallback = func;
    }
    void Call()
    {
        mycallback->Call();
    }
};
```

The idea is to make all instantiated templates of `CallbackFunction <T>` a kind-of `ICallback`. Now the class using `ICallback` can take any class `CallbackFunction <T>` without needing to know what `T` is.